# How to create a render array for a location CCK field?

Tags: 7, location, entities, theming

The situation should be common: I have a content class with one location field; in the page view of the class I show the location on map. But, at the top of the page, I want to print the address too.

In the 'manage display' of my content type, I can choose for 'map only' (formatter location_map); which is perfect for the map, or for 'default (address only)' (formatter location_default), which is perfect for the top of the page.

It is probably as easy as, something like, in the node.tpl.php, saying

```
// address here
$content['field_location']['#formatter']="location_default";
drupal_render($content['field_location']);

// google map here
$content['field_location']['#formatter']="location_map";
drupal_render($content['field_location']);
```

but that doesnt work. I also notice Location has a theming hook, described here

http://drupal.org/node/62486

unfortunately they forget to mention what goes in there. whatever i put in there, it doesnt pass to location.tpl.php (allthough it does pass that template in vain).

I have a workaround thats so ugly I'm not even going to post it here :-)
Does anyone know how to do this properly ?

*-pike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, ..in my node.tpl.php

```
// address here
$fvf = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_location', array(
    'type'=>'location_default')
);
print render($fvf);

// google map here
print render($content['field_location']);
```

Great article: http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way

pfew,
*-pike

Comment: You should mark this post as answer even it is your own.